# Search of Any in a Generic LIst (VB to C# conversion)

Tags: c#, vb.net, generic-list

I have inherited a VB application and am looking for converting some things to C# (part of migration). I have an extension method in VB that is like this:

```
<Extension()>
    Public Function ContainsAnyOf(Of T)(SourceList As List(Of T), ParamArray ParamList() As T) As Boolean
        If SourceList IsNot Nothing AndAlso ParamList IsNot Nothing Then
            For Each ParamItem As T In ParamList
                If SourceList.Contains(ParamItem) Then Return True
            Next
        End If
        Return False
    End Function
```

I have translated it to C# as follows:

```
public static bool ContainsAnyOf<T>(this List<T> sourceList, IEnumerable<T> parameters)
        {
            if (parameters.Count() == 0 || sourceList == null || sourceList.Count < 1)
            {
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
                foreach (var parameter in parameters)
                {
                    if (sourceList.Contains(parameter))
                        return true;
                    else
                        return false;
                }

                return false;
            }
        }
```

To be complete, the model is declared in a separate cs-file as follows:

```
public class TestModel
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string ModelValue1 { get; set; }
        public string ModelValue2 { get; set; }
        public bool ModelBool { get; set; }
    }
```

In a testapplication (console) I have following testcode:

```
var testAnyOf = false;
var testElement = new List<string>(){ "Test 2", "Testje 2" };

if (model.ContainsAnyOf(testElement))
{
    testAnyOf = true;
}

Console.WriteLine($"Does the list contains the {testElement}? Outcome = {testAnyOf}");
Console.ReadLine();
```

But I get a compiler error CS0411: The type arguments for method 'ListExtensions.ContainsAnyOf(List, IEnumerable)' canot be inferred from the usage ...

I know that what the Error means but I have tried few things now but still don't know how to pass the 'Parameters'.

Eventually what I need is like in the original VB application and that works like:

```
bool isInList = alistOfModel.ContainsAnyOf("One", "Dog", "Hat")
```

I think the first part with the List of type T is correct but how to pass the parameters..
Thanks!

Comment: What is the declaration of `model`?

Comment: I updated the question with the model. So everybody can learn from my "mistake" :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That should compile if `model` is of type `List<string>`. I assume that `model` is of some other type.

However, I would implement this using Linq like so (likely to be much more performant):

```
public static bool ContainsAnyOf<T>(this IEnumerable<T> sourceList, IEnumerable<T> parameters)
{
    return sourceList.Intersect(parameters).Any();
}
```

You could also use `params` so that you can call it with an argument list of items to match:

```
public static bool ContainsAnyOf<T>(this IEnumerable<T> sourceList, params T[] parameters)
{
    return sourceList.Intersect(parameters).Any();
}
```

Using the latter, instead of writing

```
var testElement = new List<string>(){ "Test 2", "Testje 2" };

if (model.ContainsAnyOf(testElement))
```

You could write

```
if (model.ContainsAnyOf("Test 2", "Testje 2"))
```

Comment: Thanks to this, I found the solution and it was easier than I first thought thanks to this help. I was comparing a string to an object and I did that wrong in the translation. So I used this answer (the intersect way).

Answer (score 2):

If you want a direct translation of that VB code then this is it:

```cs
public bool ContainsAnyOf<T>(this List<T> SourceList, params T[] ParamList)
{
    if (SourceList != null && ParamList != null)
    {
        foreach (T ParamItem in ParamList)
        {
            if (SourceList.Contains(ParamItem))
                return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

If you're going to be translating VB to C# then I suggest that you download and install [Instant C#](https://www.tangiblesoftwaresolutions.com/product_details/vb-to-csharp-converter.html) from Tangible Software Solutions.

BTW, there's never any point to null-checking a parameter declared `params`/`ParamArray` as they will always have a value. They may be empty but the array will always exist.

Comment: I upvoted this solution as it was part of the solution... ALso the link to Tangible Software Solutions will be helpfull in the future. Thanks!

Comment: "they will always have a value" is not strictly true: you can explicitly pass a `null` array `myList.ContainsAnyOf((string[])null)`

Comment: True, I tested it and the extension-method can be forced into an exception so I updated my code with a simple null check because I want control over what to send back

Comment: @Charlieface, good point. Hadn't considered that.